# TreeCellRenderer eating CPU

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtree

I have a simple TreeCellRenderer which extracts a JButton from the node, and outputs it to the JTree.

```
public class ButtonCellRenderer extends JButton implements TreeCellRenderer {

  @Override
  public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean     selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
    //setBackgroundNonSelectionColor(tree.getBackground());
    ProgressButton b = null;
    if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
      Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
      if (userObject instanceof ProgressButton) {
        b = (ProgressButton) userObject;
        return b;
      }
    }
    if (b == null) {
      System.out.println("Null!");
      DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
      return defaultRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,
              value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Returning label");
      return new JLabel(b.getToolTipText(), b.getIcon(), SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why, but it seems to be stuck looping, and eats about 30~50% CPU. Is there any way to eliminate this? Or not have to use a renderer to output a JButton into a tree?

I've added the revised code above, but now I'm getting a problem where the buttons don't display properly (they all come out small).

Comment: Why call the `super` method at the beginning? (It's probably not the problem, but it does seem redundant.)

Comment: I'm not completely sure, it was in the example I saw and I guess I just overlooked it. Removing it doesn't seem to do a lot, however.

Comment: don't create a new label each time around (though the effect shouldn't be as large as 30/50%). The validate is unneeded (after all, it's only a label) What is ProgressButton? Any chance it's doing something dirty in the background?

Comment: A ProgressButton is just a button with a JProgressBar built in (albeit, not currently working). Thanks for the tip, it's down to around 25~40 now..better!

Comment: don't store components in the model - instead store a value (f.i. an int for progress). Implement a custom renderer (f.i. a progressBar) and configure that bar with the value.

Comment: Basic rule: If you are creating components anywhere in `getTreeCellRendererComponent` you are doing something wrong. A `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` (Tree?) is a component also (but will never created in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `super.getTreeCellRendererComponent` without storing the value. If later on no renderer is created you call this method again (`if c==null...`). This is expensive for itself.

More important:

A renderer should be a component that is reused and only configured for the specific value to be shown. This is why the default implementation reuses a label and just sets the text, colors, border... That is why renderer calls are quite cheap.

You create a new `JLabel` every time you show a value: `returnLab = new JLabel(text);`. This is expensive. This method will be called for each and every cell shown on each repaint event. This is much more expensive than building a grid of components and defies the whole purpose of the renderer concept.

Please have a look into the default renderer implementation to see how to do it correctly. And have a look into the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display).

Comment: Thanks, although I have corrected those errors now. The reality of what I want to do is just to display JButtons in a JTree, and the only way I found that worked was using a renderer.

Comment: You can use a JButton as renderer just don't recreate it on every call. And it will not be a live button but just "stamped in" - that's why your setTooltip call is useless. If you want buttons you need to write an editor too and change the on click behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow read "Table" instead of Tree. I updated the reference. If enabled, setting the tooltip works. The principles are the same.